# Azure The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: azure

I have a issue with Azure, i want to process an excel file and i get the error "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.".

I had installed the AccessDataBaseEngine 2007 in my pc and i get the same error message.

What can i do?

Comment: this seem to have been answered before,  does that help - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938052/error-on-only-azure-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-t

Answer (score 0):

> If you only need to work with Excel 2007 formats or later (xlsx), you
>   can use the OpenXml SDK. This SDK requires installation on your local
>   machine. But you can simply reference the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll
>   assembly in your Web/Worker Role, and set Copy Local to true. It will
>   work in the cloud. It also doesn't require Office to be installed on
>   the cloud machine.

For more information check [**Error on only Azure - 'Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/dea3746e-d5ae-4ccc-af0f-9a0e708d32aa) and [**The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/106756/)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: thank you Sampath for your answer, but i resolved the problem whit NPOI, a open project for read/write xls files.

Comment: @gar336 OK. Great.And also include some useful links for the open project (NPOI).