# How to get only letters from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string and need the letters from said string.

```
string s = "EMA123_33";    // I need "EMA"
string s = "EMADRR123_33"; // I need "EMADRR"
```

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: why the downvotes and the close-votes if I may ask? Ok the question is not "good english" but I think the meaning is not so unclear based on the samples

Comment: Why the vote down? Yeah, he said "alphabets" when he meant "letters", but it's otherwise a totally legitimate question.

Comment: »alphabet« to mean »letter« is a common mistake made by people of Indic origins. Just get used to the fact that SO is used by people not from the US ...

Comment: to sad there is no way to downvote/punish *unjust* downvotes ....

Comment: I DO think it's too localized... But I'm too lazy to flag it for close... And I'll give him a +1 because he didn't ask for a Regex!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var myString = "EMA123_33";
var onlyLetters = new String(myString.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

please note: this version will find "e" just like "E" - if you need only upper-case letters then do something like this:

```
var myString = "EMA123_33";
var onlyLetters = new String(myString.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c) && Char.IsUpper(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `Chars` property, the string is enumerable, however you need to use `ToArray` to create an array for the string constructor,  you can't make a string from an `IEnumerable<Char>`.

Comment: ah - thanks...(didn't check) - BTW: I think the .Chars is more readable - but that may be a matter of taste

Comment: I couldn't even get it to compile using `Chars`. The indexer is named `Chars`, so you can use `s.Chars(0)` in VB but it's `s[0]` in C#.

Comment: Worth nothing you need to add "using System.Linq;" in order to use this solution.

Comment: This is beautiful! I love seeing Linq in action, now even doing what only Regex could do before!

Comment: # string to String

Comment: perfect, congrats

Answer (score 16):

You can use a regular expression to replace all non-letters:

```
string s2 = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^A-Z]+", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Carten's answer has the benefit of working with non-roman alphabets. You should consider using UTF character classes (`\p{IsLetter}` I think)

Comment: @Richard Szalay: Yes, that is an alternative. It depends on what behaviour the OP wants.

Comment: \*twitches\* Richard, those are Unicode character classes. UTF only labels the transformation formats for Unicode and does not refer to the character set, actually.

Comment: This returned empty string for me

Answer (score 4):

If you're just after the *initial* letters, i.e. those at the start of the string (your examples are a bit unclear in that I don't know what would happen to letters at the end of the string), you can use a different Regex:

```
string s2 = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\p{L}+).*", "$1");
```

Comment: Even if this were an additional requirement, I think that changing Carten's answer to use `TakeWhile` would be more efficient and easier to understand/maintain.

Comment: Probably, probably not. When reading code that deals with string manipulations I'd rather take regular expressions than LINQ, I think.

Comment: Fair, but I'd hazard a guess that the majority people are more fimilar with LINQ than they are with Unicode character classes and their syntax in Regex.

Comment: @Richard: That's precisely what makes Joey's answer interesting: It teaches us something we may not know about regexes ;-)

Comment: I think: the more (different) answers to a question the better - whoever asked the question can decide for himself - +1 (BTW: I had to search to find what this regex was doing - I just don't like them too much)

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex MyRegex = new Regex("[^a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string s = MyRegex.Replace(@"your 76% strings &*81 gose _ here and collect you want_{ (7 438 ?. !`", @"");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

**output**

`yourstringsgosehereandcollecyouwant`