# Is there any alternate to replace special characters and the numbers in the given string in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string with some mixed value like `Hi @ Rohit123`.

I have a long method to replace the special characters and display 
`HiRohit`.

Can you please suggest some alternative to this method?

My C# code is

```
 string str1 = str.Replace(" ", "").Replace("`", "").Replace("~", "").Replace("!", "")
                            .Replace("@", "").Replace("#", "").Replace("$", "").Replace("%", "").Replace("^", "")
                            .Replace("&", "").Replace("*", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "")
                            .Replace("_", "").Replace("=", "").Replace("+", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "")
                            .Replace("|", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace(":", "").Replace(";", "")
                            .Replace("'", "").Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("?", "")
                            .Replace(">", "").Replace("<", "").Replace("1", "").Replace("2", "").Replace("3", "")
                            .Replace("4", "").Replace("5", "").Replace("6", "").Replace("7", "").Replace("8", "")
                            .Replace("9", "").Replace("0", "");
```

Comment: So you want to remove all non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: I'd have a look at RegEx and the numerous search patterns you can use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only letters from a string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316258/how-to-get-only-letters-from-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to remove all non-alphabetic symbols:

```
var s = "Hi @ Rohit123";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

This regular expression replaces sequences `+` of symbols which are not `^` alphabetic symbols `a-zA-Z` with empty string.

Output

```
"HiRohit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using foreach loop :

```
// make an array of your signs 
string[] signs_to_replace = new string[] { " ", "`", "~", "!" ... };
// make a placeholder for the string
string str1 = str;
// iterate through all of the signs and replace them
foreach(string sign_to_replace in signs_to_replace) 
    str1 = str1.Replace(sign_to_replace, string.Empty);
```

Or using Linq :

```
// make an array of your signs 
char[] chars_to_replace = new char[] { ' ', '`', '~', '!' ... };
// create new string of selected characters
str1 = new string(str1.Where(c => !chars_to_replace.Contains(c)));
```

But if you know the range of characters you want : *( let's assume 'a'`0x61` to 'z'`0x7A` )*. Then it would be easier to use this `Linq` :

```
string str1 = new string(str.Where(c => c >= 'a'/*0x61*/ && c <= 'z'/*0x7A*/));
// or including capital leters :
string str1 = new string(str.Where(c => (c >= 'a'/*0x61/* && c <= 'z'/0x7A*/) || (c >= 'A'/*0x41/* && c <= 'Z'/*0x5A*/));
```