# Reading Excel data into DataTable

Tags: c#, openxml

Hi all I have my excel with the following Rows and columns

```
SKU  Quantity  Line Price  Unit Price  Line Discount
XYZ     2          4            2           1
```

case 2

```
SKU  Quantity  Line Price  Unit Price  Line Discount
XYZ     2                                 1
```

**In case2 after excecuting Line Discount value is showing in Line Price**

```
public static DataSet LoadExcelData(string pUserID, string pFilePath)
    {
            DataSet lDSExcel = new DataSet();
            DataTable lDTExcel = new DataTable();

            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(pFilePath, false))
            {

                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
                string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
                Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
                SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
                IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

                foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(0))
                {
                    lDTExcel.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell));
                }

                foreach (Row row in rows)
                {
                    DataRow tempRow = lDTExcel.NewRow();

                    for (int i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
                    {
                        tempRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));
                    }

                    lDTExcel.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                }
                lDSExcel.Tables.Add(lDTExcel);
            }
            lDTExcel.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
            return lDSExcel;
      }

public static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
    {
            string value = string.Empty;
            SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
            //if (cell.CellValue != null)
            //    value = cell.CellValue.InnerXml;

            if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
                return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
            }
            else
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is giving an exception can some one help me

Comment: What kind of exception? Could you please show actual message?

Comment: Have you imported required Namespace ?

Comment: Yes name space was included, exception is `string is not in correct format` i.e due to `return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;` when an empty string is there

Answer (score 0):

In the function GetCellValue(), change the shared string return portion to:

```
return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText)].InnerText;
```

You were parsing an empty string (the variable "value", which was initialised with an empty string). I'll leave you with error checking on cell.CellValue in case *that's* not initialised...

Comment: You need to keep track of the 'missing' cells in the xlsx, and then in your dataset/datatable, insert a blank or DBNull value in it's place.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837981/reading-excel-open-xml-is-ignoring-blank-cells?lq=1