# Empty rows are getting skipped while getting data from Excel to DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, openxml, worksheet

#### Task

Import data from excel to DataTable

#### Problem

Some of Rows that does not contain any data are getting skipped and the very next Row that has data in the row is used as the value of the empty Row

> In Excel Totally in have 37 Rows when i use openxml to convert excel
> to Datatable it skipped empty rows and read 29 rows only

```
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();
foreach (Row row in rows) //this will also include your header row...
{
    DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();
    int ko = row.Descendants<Cell>().Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
    {
        tempRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i));
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the same problem as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837981/reading-excel-open-xml-is-ignoring-blank-cells

Comment: Empty Cells not issue for me. it's coming perfectly. when i have a Empty ROWS it's skipped the rows.  In Excel Totally in have 37 Rows It's read 29 rows only.

Comment: Did my answer below help you solve the problem? Or do you need more input to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Open XML markup of an Excel worksheet, you will see that empty rows don't even exist in the markup. This means that when you are reading your rows in your `foreach` loop, you will skip those empty, non-existent rows right there.

If you want those empty rows in your `DataTable`, you will have to read each existing row, keeping track of the last row number you have seen. If there is a gap between the current row number and the last row number you have seen, you need to fill in the gap, adding empty `DataRow` instances before you add a new `DataRow` for the current row.

#### Update 2020-02-03

To find out how you can determine the row numbers, you should look at the Open XML markup of a sample worksheet. For example, the following markup shows a reduced and simplified example worksheet with just the `sheetData` element and a number of `row` child elements. You will see that each `row` element (instance of `Row` class) has an attribute called `r` (`RowIndex` property of `Row` class), which specifies the row index. In this example, we see rows 2, 3, 5, and 8, so we see that rows 4, 6, and 7 are missing.

```xml
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <sheetData>
    <row r="2" spans="2:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
      <c r="B2">
        <v>2</v>
      </c>
    </row>
    <row r="3" spans="2:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
      <c r="B3">
        <v>3</v>
      </c>
    </row>
    <row r="5" spans="2:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
      <c r="B5">
        <v>5</v>
      </c>
    </row>
    <row r="8" spans="2:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
      <c r="B8">
        <v>8</v>
      </c>
    </row>
  </sheetData>
</worksheet>
```

Comment: thanks @Thomas                                                                                                              
when we debug the first line of  =>                                                                              using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file, false))                                                                               It's return 29 rows only.                                                                                               then how can i check row numbers.

Comment: @rajadurai, I updated my answer, showing some sample markup with multiple rows (`row` elements with `r` attribute) and pointing out the relevant strongly-typed class (`Row` with `RowIndex` property).

Comment: Ya it's worked for me. thanks @Thomas . Based on previous and current row value i added empty rows if any rows missing.

Comment: @rajadurai, sounds good. Then please accept this answer and upvote.